# java swing jlist data transferring

Tags: java, swing, jlist

**jList2.setListData(jList1.getSelectedValues());**
I used this, to transfer data from a jlist1 to jlist2. But I want to remove the transferred data from jlist1. How it can be.

Answer (score 1):

First: `getSelectedValues()` is deprecated, use `getSelectedValuesList()` to get them as a List using generics.

Second, create a DefaultListModel before creating your JList so you can add/remove to/from it, e.g.

```
DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
DefaultListModel<String> model2 = new DefaultListModel<String>();
JList<String> list1 = new JList<>(model);
JList<String> list2 = new JList<>(model2);

...

for(String s : list1.getSelectedValuesList()){
    model2.addElement(s);
    model.removeElement(s);
}
```

Remember that changes to the list and models **must** be performed on the event dispatch thread

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways

- to look at Drag an Drop tutorial on Oracle pages
- on mouseDragged to remove selectedItem from one JList and to add to the seconds, notice this idea required better knowledge about Java Swing

Comment: The OP never actually states that Drag and Drop are being used, the question could apply to any scenario where data moves between lists.

Comment: It's good to have alternatives; I'd also consider something like [this](http://wiki.netbeans.org/wiki/images/a/a3/Persistence-Entity-1_UsingVWICEfacesWithNetBeans.gif).